# RootViewController won't add subview when accessed outside its delegate

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have this code compiled with no error, but I can't make **welcomeUIView** to be displayed.

Yes, when I move it inside **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** it will show up. But why I can't make it the way I want?

Here is the console out:

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
view()
finished
```

The code:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
static UIWindow *window;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@end
```

**AppDelegate.mm**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
std::cout<<"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"<<std::endl;
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

view *v = new view();
v->set();

// Override point for customization after application launch.
window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

std::cout<<"finished"<<std::endl;

return YES;
}
```

**view.mm**

```
#include "view.h"
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <iostream>

void view::set()
{
std::cout<<"view()"<<std::endl;

UIView *welcomeUIView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[welcomeUIView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

[welcomeUIView setHidden:false];
[window.rootViewController.view addSubview:welcomeUIView];
[window.rootViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:welcomeUIView];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is that `window` is declared as `static` in your header, so each translation unit will have its own distinct `window`.

You've set the `window` variable within AppDelegate.mm, but then in view.mm you have a different `window` which is still nil. If you meant to share `window` you should declare is `extern` in your header and then define it within AppDelegate.mm.

Also, you should just let your view controller set up its own view hierarchy by subclassing UIViewController and overriding `loadView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add the view in your root view controller. Do it in `viewDidLoad`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 

    UIView *welcomeView = 
          [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    welcomeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor;
    [self.view addSubview:welcomeView];
}
```

This will, however not cover the whole screen if you have a status bar or navigation bar. Instead, you can add the view to `self.view.window` (with the CGRect from your code).